# Managing user location with session variable - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, redirect

I'm using the WP Session plugin to store the location of visitors to my site. When a visitor comes to the site for the first time (http://www.mypage.com/), my homepage template simply tries to guess the location, store it in a session variable, and redirects the user to the appropriate homepage for his location (ex. http://www.mypage.com/location/sydney).

So far it works fine. However, I'm starting to think on what could happen if a visitor comes back using the full location url (http://www.mypage.com/location/sydney or any other url within my site) after his session already expired. Since the user is skipping the homepage, the session variable will never be set and some functionality won't work.

How can I make sure that regardless of the page, the location variable is always set? In other words: on every page, check if the session variable is set. Otherwise, redirect to the homepage where detection takes place.

I dont want to add this check to every single template. Would it be a good idea to place it in the header?

**Edit:**

Redirecting to the homepage where the detection is done is probably not a good idea. If the person is coming to read a specific post but doesn't have a session, he will be redirected to the homepage and wont be able to see the post he was looking for in the first place unless he searches for it again.

What if I place the location detection function in the header? If the user doesn't have a session, I create the session there and let him see the post he was looking for in the first place.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

**index.php**

```
/*
 * Template Name: Index
 */     

$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
if (!isset($wp_session['city'])) {
    $wp_session['city'] = detect_city();    
}

wp_redirect(home_url() . '/location/' . $wp_session['city'] . '/');
exit;
```

Comment: Why'd you add it to "template"? Does WordPress not separate Logic from View?

Comment: Im sorry, but I don't get your question... I'll post my landing page template to clarify

Comment: I dunno, wordpress code is so ugly.. but generally, you'd check if the URL is one that is for the city, and if it is and variable is not set, set it to the city. Otherwise do the guesswork.